# working with a 2D array vs flatting it to reduce runtime in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, runtime, benchmarking

I am dealing with a single 2D array and my goal is to reduce the runtime of my function(written in C) as much as possible. I'm doing statistical calculations on the 2D array such as finding the average and minimum value. So, there are nested loops involved to calculate such attributes. Would converting the 2D array into 1D array give me a boost in performance in this case?

Comment: Probably no; a 2D array is already contiguous in memory.  Although if the compiler doesn't "see through" that and is making nested loops, manually doing 2D indexing might help a bit if you're not memory-bound.